# What to report with mixed-effect models?

Tags: mixed-model, variance, linear, effect-size

I am running a mixed-effect linear regression model: DV ~ IV + (1|RandomEffect).

DV is a numerical variable, and IV is a categorical variable.

Now I am confused about what to report about the results of the model.

The must-report items are: F-value, df, p, Coef.

However, I am hesitating between R squared and eta squared.

I want to report the marginal R squared (say 0.001) and conditional R squared (say 0.5), with [r.squaredGLM](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MuMIn/versions/1.43.17/topics/r.squaredGLMM), because I want to make the following argument: despite the IV is significant, it could only explain a very small amount of variance in the DV, while the random effect was more powerful in explaining the variance.

Should I also report eta squared?

Comment: There are two typos with "sqaured" but I cannot edit.

Comment: Just report the point estimate and the confidence interval for the IV.  F-value, df, p value and any measure of $R^2$ are unnecessary